# CSS Text shadow with greater offsets

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, less

I Need a little help in making the outline effect like in the image below:

[image: This is how it should look like]

I tried using CSS text-shadow property but its not working as same as i want.

```
text-shadow:
    6px 6px 0 #000,
    /* Simulated effect for Firefox and Opera
       and nice enhancement for WebKit */
   -6px -6px 0 #000,  
    6px -6px 0 #000,
   -6px  6px 0 #000,
    6px  6px 0 #000;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <style>
body{

    font-family: 'Arial Black';
background-color: rgb(252, 225, 255);
}




    </style>
    
    
    <title>Mental Health</title></head>
<body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="100">
        

        <g
          fill="white"
          stroke="#aa0988"
          stroke-width="6"
         
          text-anchor="middle"
          font-family="sans-serif"
          font-size="20px"
          font-weight="bold">
          
          <text x="80" y="50" paint-order="stroke" id="stroke-under">
           Mental Health
          </text>
        </g>
      </svg>
      
</body>


</html>
```

This is pretty close, except for the pointy M, that could be fixed by increasing the Y. This works in Edge, so it should work in chrome too, as edge is chrome based.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #E8D6E9;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
}

span:nth-child(1) {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 128px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 30px #A155A5;
}
span:nth-child(2) {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 128px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>Mental Health</span>
  <span>Mental Health</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use this it gives me a really nice effect like the text is glowing.

```
text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px white;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).